# Fabric.js version 2.x getActiveGroup() depreciated and breaking application

Tags: fabricjs

fabricjs is a super canvas drawing library...

In version 2.x of fabric.js getActiveGroup() has been depreciated and I'm struggling to understand what replaces it.

I have a canvas with multiple group objects on it. Prior to version 2 getActiveGroup() would return null for a single object selected or a group if a multiSelect had taken place. (ie click and drag on canvas to highlight and select multiple groups - a group of groups in effect)

This seems to have been replaced by getActiveObject() in version 2. This always seems to return a group, either a single object group OR a group of groups if multi-select has taken place.

Is getActiveObject() the replacement getActiveGroup() ? or am I missing something?

This used to work prior to version 2.x

```
canvas.on('object:moving'), function(e){    
    let activeGroup = canvas.getActiveGroup()

    if ( activeGroup ){
         // do something with a multi select - a group of groups
    } else {
         // do something with a single select - a single group
    }
}
```

feeling dumb...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

getActiveObject() will return always the selected object.

If a single object is selected it will return it, as it is, as a reference.

If multiple objects are selected, it will return an object of type 'ActiveSelection' that is derived from group.

A new method called 'getActiveObjects()' will always return a freshly created array with all the selected objects, may it be one or more.

Comment: Thanks Andrea (great work on fabric btw)

How do I test for this 'type' ?

Comment: if ( activeGroup instanceof fabric.ActiveSelection ){ // multi select happened

seems to work ok

Comment: well each object has a type property or you could use instaceof, with the exception that an ActiveSelection is an instanceof ActiveSelection, but also Group amd also Object because is a subclass

Comment: Is it possible to edit the getActiveObjects elements? like  this.canvas.getActiveObject().toObject().set({
        stroke: DrawingColours.YELLOW,
        strokeWidth: DrawingThickness.THICK});